# How do I make cloth bags from pig tails?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

What are the steps to go from pig tails to cloth bags?  The wiki says the process plants/thresher skill is used to turn the pig tails into thread.  I used the spin thread task, and my dwarf that has plant processor enabled has never gone and done it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The step-by-step guide to turning pig-tails into useable cloth is as follows:

1. Grow pig-tails, or order your herbalists to scrounge the caverns for 'naturally grown' pig-tails.
2. At a Farmer's Workshop (<kbd>b</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>), order a dwarf to 
   <kbd>p</kbd>rocess plants, turning the raw plant into usable plant threads. This task requires the "Thresher" labor
3. At a Loom (<kbd>b</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>), order a dwarf to <kbd>w</kbd>eave cloth (plant thread). This task requires the "Weaving" labor.
4. At a Clothier's Workshop (<kbd>b</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>), finally you can order a dwarf (with the clothesmaking labor) to make cloth bags. (Select cloth, rather than silk or yarn, and then select bag, which is either 'n' or 'b').

Comment: Optionally, step 2a or 3a will be to have a dorf with the dyeing labor dye the thread or cloth to increase its value.

Comment: I might also add that the weaving task is usually automatic unless you've turned off the order for it (under the orders-Workshops submenu). But you do need to have a Loom, which you might be missing. Spin Thread is for turning raw wool (sheared from an alpaca) into thread, which can then also be woven.

Comment: Now we can tell the clothier which material should be used, just press d in the job manager/workshop.